# How to Get iPhone Video or Photo's Geotag? Using UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller, photo, geotagging

I am building an app that allows user to pick videos/photos from camera or photo library.

If picked from photo library, is it possible to access to the video or photo's geotag? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can see an overview of how to approach this issue at the following related links:

Online guide available here:
http://iphone-land.blogspot.com/

Iphone-EXIF Guide here:
http://iphone-exif.googlecode.com/files/iphone-exif-guide-0.8.pdf

Downloadble source codes here:
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/

I hope this is enough to guide you :)

Comment: According to the documentation, the iphone-exif library is for reading and writing of geotag for jpeg images only.  Anyone know of a library for reading/writing geotags for videos?

Comment: Any valid information on geotags for videos using UIImagePickerView?